# jQuery Responsive Menu - Automatically collapse menu after clicking anchor link?

Tags: jquery, menu, navigation, responsive

I created a pretty simple responsive navigation with a menu icon using jquery. Everything seems to work properly; however, I am struggling on how to make the menu automatically collapse when an anchor link is clicked in the mobile menu.

Here's the html:

```
<header>
    <a href="#home" id="logo"><h1>Logo</h1></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="menu-icon"><i class="icon-menu"></i></a>
    <nav id="main-navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section-1">Section 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section-2">Section 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section-3">Section 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section-4">Section 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

The CSS:

```
        #menu-icon {
                     display: none;
                     float: right;
                     padding: 33px 20px;
                     margin-bottom: -6px;
                 }

                 #menu-icon i {
                     color: white;
                 }

                #main-navigation {
                    float: right;
                    padding: 20px;
                }

                #main-navigation ul {
                    list-style: none;
                }

                #main-navigation li {
                    display: inline-block;
                    float: left;
                    padding: 10px 20px;
                    margin-top: -15px;
                }

                #main-navigation ul li a {
                    color: #fff;
                    text-decoration: none;
                }

                #main-navigation ul li a:hover {
                    border-bottom: 3px solid #3498db;
                    padding-bottom: 3px;
                }

    @media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

            #menu-icon {
                display: inline-block;
            }

            #main-navigation{
                background-color: #4d525b;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                display: none;
            }

            #main-navigation ul li {
                display: block;
                float: none;
                padding: 30px;
            }

            #main-navigation ul li a {
                font-size: 18px;
            }
        }
@media screen and (min-width:1199px) {
       #main-navigation { display:block !important; }
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#menu-icon").click(function(){
    $("#main-navigation").slideToggle("slow");
    $("#menu-icon i").toggleClass("icon-close");
});
```

Here is a CodePen with everything: https://codepen.io/lukecjohnson/pen/gePrvw

Any help would or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work as you wanted:

```
$("#menu-icon, #main-navigation a").click(function(){
    $("#main-navigation").slideToggle("slow");
    $("#menu-icon i").toggleClass("icon-close");
});
```

**Edit:** try this please. Modify media query if needed.

```
$("#menu-icon, #main-navigation a").click(function(){
  if(window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)').matches) {
    $("#main-navigation").slideToggle("slow");
    $("#menu-icon i").toggleClass("icon-close");
  }
});
```

Comment: That works great on the mobile menu but the problem is that it also hides the navigation when the full desktop is showing. So any ideas on how to make the menu items collapse the navigation only on mobile?

Comment: Ok, I see. But this problem is present even in the source code. Click menu icon in mobile view, then switch to desktop. Links wiil disappear. Let me think a bit.

Comment: I just fixed that issue by adding an additional media query. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for the help!